# Angular - Show / Hide element on focus

Tags: angular

I have an input element and a , I want to show the  if the input is selected, but hide it if anything other then the input OR one of the  items is clicked.

```
<input type="text" (focusin)="showPropertiesList=true">
<ul *ngIf="showPropertiesList">
...
</ul>
```

I tried adding focusout on the input, but that hides the  when I try to click one of its elements, I also tried document.activeElement, but that always seems to return the body tag, even when I click the , how can this be solved?

Not sure if it matters or not, but the  is an absolute position element.

Answer (score 3):

Consider wrapping both elements using a DIV element, then apply the focus-directives to it as below:

```html
<div (focusin)="show = true" (focusout)="show = false">
  <input>
  <ul *ngIf="show"> </ul>
</div>
```

[Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-herschel-s1msn?file=/src/app/app.component.css)

Comment: I've tried something similar, but this doesn't solve the (click) issue on the <li> items (trying to click a link / button on the <li> elements hides the list before the button gets clicked)

Comment: since <li> is nested within the wrapper div `focusout` event will not get fired, try my demo please.

Comment: I did try the demo, clicking any of the li items ('how', 'are') closes the window for me.